# Disable popup message in php

Tags: php, excel, com

When i upload a excel  file, i have used COM() to open and automate converting it to xml.

It works fine, But when i run it, it always shows the message from Microsoft Excel:
A file named ''' already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?
I can choose between Yes No and Cancel.
normally i would choose Yes. But i dont want users to click on Yes each time.
Can i disable this? 
Please inform me if any relevant codes need to be posted.
Thanks 
**UPDATE** Here's part of my code using unlink().

```
$workbook = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
$sheet = "Sheet1";
$ext = substr($workbook, strrpos($workbook, '.') + 1);

$ex = new COM("Excel.sheet") or die("Did not connect");

//Open the workbook that we want to use.
$wkb = $ex->application->Workbooks->Open($workbook) or die("Did not open");
$path = "D:\b2\\test1.xml";
$format = 46;
unlink($path);
$path = "D:\b2\\test1.xml";
//Create a copy of the workbook, so the original workbook will be preserved.
$ex->Application->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs($path, $format);
```

Is it the right way to use it? Because it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this line.

```
$ex->application->displayAlerts = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're always going to overwrite, the simplest way is probably just to delete the file first before you get Excel to open it. The PHP function to delete a file is [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)